# Symfony mail not working

Tags: symfony, email, nginx

I have been given an application to configure, that uses nginx w/ symfony as well as PHP and MySQL. The application is supposed to be able to reset passwords, by sending an email to the one who requested it.

However, when you click on the button, you get a notice that you will receive an email (so no error here), but in reality, the email will not be sent at all. When I use swiftmailer w/ powershell and execute the following command

```
C:\nginx\php\php.exe bin/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

I receive the email correctly, regardless to which address I send it to.
The email settings in my parameters.yml file are as follows:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtphub.example.com //not real domain name
mailer_user: ~
mailer_password: ~
mailer_address: ~
mailer_sender: ~
```

Do I need to edit this file, and with what? There is no password and user required for the email sever, as well as no port number. If I fill out the `mailer_sender` and `mailer_address`, email sending does not even work with swiftmailer. I do not want to use other services, such as gmail, as the email server is correctly set up. Should I edit another file to make this work, or how exactly do I edit this to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, basically, when you run it from the console, it defaults to the dev environment. I specifically used the command `server:run 0.0.0.0:8000 --env=prod`, so that it runs in the production environment, and it works. It gives me an error, that you should not run it from the console as production, but it works regardless.